# Chat App using Socket.io and Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, putty, filezilla

I am developing chat app using Node.js and Socket.io.
Here is my code.|

socket.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8001);
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
// open the socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   // listen for the chat even. and will recieve
   // data from the sender.
   socket.on('chat', function (data) {

      // default value of the name of the sender.
      var sender = 'unregistered';

      // get the name of the sender
      socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
         console.log('Chat Message By: ', name);
         console.log('error ', err);
         sender = name;
      });

      // broadcast data recieved from the sender
      // to others who are connected, but not
      // from the original sender.
      socket.broadcast.emit('chat', {
         msg : data,
         msgr : sender
      });
   });

   // listen for user registrations
   // then set the socket nickname to
   socket.on('register', function (name) {

      // make a nickname paramater for this socket
      // and then set its value to the name recieved
      // from the register even above. and then run
      // the function that follows inside it.
      socket.set('nickname', name, function () {

         // this kind of emit will send to all! :D
         io.sockets.emit('chat', {
            msg : "Hello " + name + '!',
            msgr : "Mr.Server"
         });
      });
   });

});
```

index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
            <script>
               var name = '';
         var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001');


         // at document read (runs only ones).
         $(document).ready(function(){


            // on click of the button (jquery thing)
            // the things inside this clause happen only when
            // the button is clicked.
            $("button").click(function(){

               // just some simple logging
               $("p#log").html('Sent message: ' + $("input#msg").val());

               // send message on inputbox to server
               socket.emit('chat', $("input#msg").val() );


               $("p#data_recieved").append("<br />\r\n" + name + ': ' + $("input#msg").val());

               // then we empty the text on the input box.
               $("input#msg").val('');
            });

            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            alert("Disconnected");
            //socket.clients[kickedUserSocketId].onDisconnect();
           socket.close();
    });

            // ask for the name of the user, ask again if no name.
            while (name == '') {
               name = prompt("What's your name?","");
            }

            // send the name to the server, and the server's
            // register wait will recieve this.
            socket.emit('register', name );
         });



         // listen for chat event and recieve data
         socket.on('chat', function (data) {

            // print data (jquery thing)
            $("p#data_recieved").append("<br />\r\n" + data.msgr + ': ' + data.msg);

            // we log this event for fun :D
            $("p#log").html('got message: ' + data.msg);

         });

         socket.emit('forceDisconnect');
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="text" id="msg"></input>
      <button>Click me</button>
      <p id="log"></p>
      <p id="data_recieved"></p>
   </body>

<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Disconnect"/>


</html>
```

I am running first socket.js from command prompt. After that, I am running .html file in browser 2 times. Now 2 users can chat via browsers. But when I am trying to put my .js file and .html file on server which I have created using FileZila and running .js file, it is running but when I am trying to run .html file on server side(In this case FileZila) , by giving the IP address and Port number of server it is not running. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What does "run .html file on server side" means? And how can you see "it is not running"? Is there a chance that you forgot to make sure that the `socket.io.js` is in the path on server side?

Comment: run.html means client will run it on browser by providing IP address.

Comment: socket.io.js where I have to make changes?

Comment: http://cuisinecode.blogspot.in/2014/05/simple-chat-application-using-nodejs.html

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a `nodejs`-issue.
You have a server that should be reachable by IP with something like 'http://your.domain.or.ip:80'.

If you get a "can't connect" in your browser then make sure there is no firewall in its way and that port (in the example: 80) is reachable from your browser location (aka known as "your pc"). Please note that you have your socket-service on port 8001 and your web server maybe runs on a different port? Make sure both ports are open.

If you get a blank page, check the browser javascript error messages.

There is a chance that you forgot to upload the file 'socket.io.js' in that directory '/socket.io/'. Try to download that file directly to see if your server serves.